# How to use Dockerfile from a cloned repository using actions/checkout@v3 with docker/build-push-action@v4

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, buildx

I have repository A that implements some CI/CD stuff to build an other repository.
I can checkout the repository:

```
      - name: Checkout Repo B
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
          repository: org/repo-B
          ref: main
          path: repoB
```

And what I want, is to simply use this cloned repo instead of the actual one to build and push the docker image.

```
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Build & Push API
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          push: true
          context: "{{defaultContext}}:repoB"
          file: apidockerfile
          tags: ${{ env.ACR_URL }}/${{ env.API_IMAGE_NAME }}:${{ inputs.api }}
          secrets: |
            GIT_AUTH_TOKEN=${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
```

The problem is that buildx never finds the repoB, it always checkout the repoA event if the context is set.

Any idea please?

Comment: Did you try verifying the path of the `Dockerfile`? And, `context: "{{defaultContext}}:repoB"` doesn't look right.

Comment: @Azeem I verified the `repoB` content and it's fine. But the context doesn't take in account this at all. It's alway on `repoA`

Comment: How did you verify it? What about the Dockerfile? Is that path correct?

Comment: @Azeem it's coming from repoB, the checkout step. Yes it's verified. Now the problem is how to tell docker/build-push-action to take the dockerfile from repoB and not checkout repoA

Comment: `file` takes a path. You can specify the path of the Dockerfile in it. See https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#inputs.

Comment: @Azeem: As I said, the path is the one from the checkout of another repo. The actual build-push-action will fetch the actual repository.

Comment: Is your second repo public? If not, could you please reproduce this with a public repo? Please share its link here. I'll try to reproduce it on my side.

Comment: @Azeem it's not public but you can easily reproduce it from what I shared.

Comment: Just tested your scenario. It's working fine for me. See and verify this [workflow](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/4446674119/workflow) and [run](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/4446674119/jobs/7807273994).

Comment: @Azeem It's working for you because when you checkout the second project, you override the actual path with it, so test folder contains only the newly checked one. Add `path: repoX` to your checkouts and then try.
In the first checkout add path: repoA and in the second one add path: repoB
And use this in your context.

Comment: Working fine with `path: repoB` and `context: ./repoB`. See https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/4446674119/workflow.